# Phpmyadmin page shows lines of code on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

After I installed PHPMyAdmin on my ubuntu server 16.04, instead of showing the PHPMyAdmin page it was showing lines of code which I think is the source code for the login page. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A silly question from my side, but have you installed php5 or php on your server?

Comment: @eranga I have php installed

Comment: have you installed libapache2-php5 module?. You can use apt-get command to install the php module

Comment: correct command is apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: "The mysqli|mysql extension is missing." is the new error I am getting after installing libapache2-mod-php5.

Comment: apt-get install php5-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You are missing core modules required to run a LAMP web application.

Install the below packages & check your PHPmyADMIN page

```
apt-get -y install php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```